# ERROR: throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")

Tags: android, flutter

I had recently made a new project in flutter but there's an error in build.gradle file in VS Code showing **{throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")}**.

Tried adding SDK path in android studio but it didn't worked also i changed the above error statement to ("throw FileNotFoundException...") it solved the error but my project didn't run on the emulator.

[Build.gradle.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ijv7.png)

(Do let me know if any other images or anything else is needed from my side.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit local.properties in the android folder

sdk.dir=/Users/sunnysaini/Library/Android/sdk

flutter.sdk=/Users/sunnysaini/development/flutter

Comment: I have already updated the path in local.properties in the android folder but still the same problem exists. (flutter.sdk= C\:\\Users\\PC\\Downloads\\flutter_windows_2.5.3-stable\\flutter)

Answer (score 0):

The latest Android SDK does not support **GradleException()**, instead uses **FileNotFoundException()** or **RuntimeException().**